# Setting CURL connect and execute timeouts in PHP

Tags: php, curl, timeout

I'm running an apache server in a Raspberry Pi, which is connecting to ESP8266 WiFi modules from a PHP script using CURL. It works fine with an automatic answer from the modules (i.e. as soon as they receive the http query, they answer), but it's timing out almost instantly when it depends on a human action before responding (i.e. a button must be pushed to answer the http query).

I have the following configuration, where what I want is to give the script 5 seconds to establish a connection, and then give another 12 seconds to the module to answer before timing out:

```
$curl = curl_init("http://10.0.0.100:51813/?getVars=values");
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Custom UserAgent",
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 5,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 12,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json'),
    CURLOPT_INTERFACE => "uap0"
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

I'd expect for the script to timeout after 5 seconds if no connection was established (`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`), and if it connected then I'd expect it to timeout after 12 seconds if no answer is received (`CURLOPT`_TIMEOUT).

In my tests it's timing out after 3 secs (on mean) for connection, and it's timing out immediately after connecting (so it's not waiting said 12 secs).

Do you have any idea why?

Note: The problem can't be from the wifi module. The WiFi module gets the request, then waits for user interaction (for 10 secs). If the user pushes the button, it sends the request. If not, it closes the connection. If I remove from the module's code the part where it waits for the user to interact, it sends the answer and everything works fine (except for the user not interacting)

Comment: Hi! So what is the question? This is not working for you? What are the symptoms?

Comment: Hi! Well, I'd expect for the script to timeout after 5 seconds if no connection was established (`CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`), and if it connected then I'd expect it to timeout after 12 seconds if no answer is received (`CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`). In my tests it's timing out after 3 secs (on mean) for connection, and it's timing out inmediately after connecting (so it's not waiting said 12 secs).

Comment: Could the other end (the WiFi modules) be closing the connection prematurely?

Comment: No, the WiFi module gets the request, then waits for user interaction (for 10 secs). If the user pushes the button, it sends the request. If not, it closes the connection. If I remove from the module's code the part where it waits for the user to interact, it sends the answer and everything works fine (except for the user not interacting).

Comment: For what I know, the curl is properly configured and it should work. So it's really giving me a headache :S

Comment: I've heard of a weird thing before, where you need to set the timeout options right before the call ti `curl_exec();`... Maybe you want to use that? (`curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 12);`)

Comment: @MacPrawn I've edited the question to show the init and exec parts ;)

Comment: Yeah - even that for a while wouldn't work properly. Try moving your timeout settings in separate curl_setopt calls, right before the exec... It really shouldn't matter, but at this point, might as well try everything...

Comment: Add directives for `verbose` and trace or what not to get some more insight.  Sure the issue is client side and not the server closing the connection?  Using wire shark or something to sniff?